# Horizontal Menu CSS Material UI ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am trying to do a horizontal menu with ReactJS and Material UI, but I have the following problem: My menu shows correctly, in horizontal, but it is not responsive. When I change the size of the page in the browser, my menu continues to have the same size like before. It only updates its size when I reload with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import NavigationMenu from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/menu';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';

const style = {
  display: 'inline-block',
  margin: '0 32px 16px 0',
  width: '100%'
};

const styleq = {
  display: 'inline',
  float: 'left',
  width: '25%'
};

export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar
                title={<span style={STYLES.title}>- PLATAFORMA DE INCIDENCIAS -</span>}
                onTitleTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
                titleStyle={STYLES.titleStyle}
                iconElementLeft={this.state.drawerOpen ?  <IconButton><NavigationClose/></IconButton> : <IconButton><NavigationMenu/></IconButton>}
                onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.controlMenu}
            />
            <Paper style={style}>
              <Menu>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Maps"  style={styleq}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Books"  style={styleq}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Flights" style={styleq} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Apps" style={styleq} />
              </Menu>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same question and it has been driving me crazy! lol. I love MUI, but sometimes all the nesting can make things really difficult...
Anyway, this worked for me. Keep your MenuItems as they are and change your Menu props to this:

`<Menu autoWidth={false} width="100%" listStyle={{width: '0.01%'}} style={{width:'100%'}}>`

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an element with a fixed width.

Is there a URL where to see it working or something that could help me understand what's going on? It's hard just from what you wrote.

---

UPDATE

When you use the Menu component, set the "autoWidth" props to "false".
As you can see [from the code](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/ccf712c5733508784cd709c18c29059542d6aad1/src/Menu/Menu.js#L53), the default is "true" that will force a width for the menu.

```
<Menu autoWidth={false}>
```

Comment: It is not my code but is very similar and happen the same that i want to fix.

https://jsfiddle.net/d980vcon/2/

Comment: Great! You have to set 'width:100%' to both div with id "horiz-menu" and its parent.

Comment: Thank you. I did it, I will answer again due to i can't put code here.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will answer you in other answer due to I need to put code and a Img.